# How can I convert an int to char?

Tags: java

How can I convert an int to char?

I am using:

```
int i=20;
char c= Character.forDigit(i,10);
// OR
//char c= Integer.toString(i).charAt(0); 

System.out.println(c);
```

1. I want char as '20' (NOT to treat 20 as ASCII value and printing some char whose ASCII is 20).
2. The above program works fine for single digit but for double digit like 20, it prints only first character, `2`.

How can I print  20 as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char is a single character, that is a letter, a digit, a punctuation mark, a tab, a space or something similar. A char literal is a single one character enclosed in single quote marks like this

char myCharacter = 'g';

Some characters are hard to type. For these Java provides escape sequences. This is a backslash followed by an alphanumeric code. For instance '\n' is the newline character. '\t' is the tab character. '\' is the backslash itself. The following escape sequences are defined:

\b  backspace
\t  tab
\n  linefeed
\f  formfeed
\r  carriage return
\"  double quote, "
\'  single quote, '
\  backslash, \
The double quote escape sequence is used mainly inside strings where it would otherwise terminate the string. For instance

System.out.println("And then Jim said, \"Who's at the door?\"");
It isn't necessary to escape the double quote inside single quotes. The following line is legal in Java

char doublequote = '"';

To convert into String:
    String.valueOf(20);

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `char` takes a single character (think of it as a `String` of **exactly** length 1). Doing `20` is not considered a `char` but an array containing 2 characters: `'2'`, `'0'`. Therefore you should be considering using a `String`.

To print 20 as a whole, do:

```
int i = 20;
String number = String.valueOf(i);
System.out.println(number);
```

Obviously, I can never use a `char`, so a `String` is the best way of representing characters of length greater than 1.

Here is a resource to understand [Java Primitive Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and here is the definition of a [character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: My Bad! I should have thought what i am asking. +1 for still exploring it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 25;
System.out.println("number: " + i);
```

Prints the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
String num = "20";
int i = Integer.parseInt(num, 16); // 32
```